# Form groups of individuals python (pandas)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a data set of the following form:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'Subject': ['Subject1','Subject1','Subject1','Subject2','Subject2','Subject2','Subject3','Subject3','Subject3','Subject4','Subject4','Subject4'],
'Event':['1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3'],
'Category':['1','1','2','2','1','2','2','','2','1','1',''],
'Variable1':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
'Variable2':['12','11','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1'],
'Variable3': ['-6','-5','-4','-3','-4','-3','-2','-1','0','1','2','3']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
d1=d1[['Subject','Event','Category','Variable1','Variable2','Variable3']]
d1
```

This looks as follows:

[image]

Where 
1) 'Subject' is the subject level identifier. 
2) 'Event'is the event level identifier. 
3) 'Category' is the category level identifier. 
4) Variable1, Variable2 & Variable3 are some continuous variables for each subject.

I need to make **all feasible groups of 2** for 'Subject' for 'Event' for each 'Category'.

For instance, for Event 1, the only possible pairs are:
1) Subject1 - Subject4 (For Category 1)
2) Subject2 - Subject3 (For Category 2)

**Note, if a category value is missing, then this indicates the 'Subject' is to be considered to have not taken part in the event.**

After forming each possible group, I have to take the Variable1, Variable2 and Variable3 for both 'Subject' and put them side by side.

This should look like the following:

[image]

What is important is to maintain the order in which 'Subject' appears under Match1 and Match2 columns and the ordering of Variable1, Variable2,Variable3 columns.

The possible pairingsfor Event 2 is shown below:

**Note since for Subject3, Category is blank, she does not appear in the pairings.**

[image]

Similarly, the possible pairings for Event 3 is shown below:
**Note since for Subject4, Category is blank, she does not appear in the pairings.**

[image]

The final table looks like this:

[image]

**Note that all numbers are random. In the actual dataset, I have about 15 categories each with about 1000 subjects spanning across 300 events. In some cases, some categories may have no observations for an event just as shown here.**

Please let me know if you my question is not very clear or if I made a mistake in the pair examples here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a large amount of *repeated data* in your final output. Why do you need this specific format?

Comment: I need the to prepare the data in this particular format to implement a matching model proposed by Sorensen (2007). If you check carefully, none of the pairings for a given event for a given category is repeated. The variable values are as I need to construct some other variables from them. But there is no repeat of any pairing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from  itertools import combinations

d1['Category'] = d1['Category'].mask(d1['Category'] == '')

L = [(i[0], i[1], y[0], y[1]) for i, x in d1.groupby(['Event','Category'])['Subject'] 
                              for y in list(combinations(x, 2))]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Event','Category','Match1','Match2'])

df1 = (df.rename(columns={'Match1':'Subject'})
         .merge(d1, on=['Event','Category','Subject'], how='left')
         .iloc[:, 4:]
         .add_suffix('.1'))
df2 = (df.rename(columns={'Match2':'Subject'})
         .merge(d1, on=['Event','Category','Subject'], how='left')
         .iloc[:, 4:]
         .add_suffix('.2'))

fin = pd.concat([df, df1, df2], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (fin)
  Event Category    Match1    Match2 Variable1.1 Variable2.1 Variable3.1  \
0     1        1  Subject1  Subject4           1          12          -6   
1     1        2  Subject2  Subject3           4           9          -3   
2     2        1  Subject1  Subject2           2          11          -5   
3     2        1  Subject1  Subject4           2          11          -5   
4     2        1  Subject2  Subject4           5           8          -4   
5     3        2  Subject1  Subject2           3          10          -4   
6     3        2  Subject1  Subject3           3          10          -4   
7     3        2  Subject2  Subject3           6           7          -3   

  Variable1.2 Variable2.2 Variable3.2  
0          10           3           1  
1           7           6          -2  
2           5           8          -4  
3          11           2           2  
4          11           2           2  
5           6           7          -3  
6           9           4           0  
7           9           4           0
```

**Explanation**:

1. Replace empty strings to NaNs by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)- `groupby` siletly remove these rows
2. Create `DataFrame` by list comprehension with flattening of all combinations of length `2` of column `Subject` by groups per columns `Event` and `Category`
3. Double join variable columns by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, filter out first `4` columns by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and add [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) or [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for avoid duplicated columns names
4. Last [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all 3 DataFrames together